# Query String Filtering with differnt values from same column

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

How can we filter by multiple values in a column?
Example: ?name=comapny1&name=company2

Fore example I have 5 company's and I search for products belong ti company1 and company2 the result I want to get is: table with products that belongs to company1 and company2

This is my filter:

```
class ProductFilters extends QueryFilter
{
    // maker
    public function make($maker)
    {
        return $this->builder->where('company', $maker);
    }
```

And query filter:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: dmitry
 * Date: 2017/05/10
 * Time: 2:26
 */

namespace App;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

abstract class QueryFilter
{
    protected $request;

    protected $builder;

    public function  __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public  function apply(Builder $builder)
    {
        $this->builder = $builder;

        foreach ($this->filters() as $name => $value) {
            if (method_exists($this, $name)) {
                call_user_func_array([$this, $name], array_filter([$value]));
            }

        }

        return $this->builder;
    }

    public function filters()
    {
        return $this->request->all();
    }

}
```

My form looks like this:

```
<form method="GET" action="/products" id="form1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="company[]" value="1">1</input>
  <input type="checkbox" name="company[]" value="2">2</input>
</form>
```

This is my controller:

```
public function index(Request $request, ProductFilters $filters)
    {
        $products    = Product::filter($filters)->paginate(30)->appends($request->all());
        return view('product.browse', compact('products' ));
    }
```

Comment: With regular PHP `$_GET` the parameters need to be `name[]=company1&name[]=company2`. I don't know if Laravel is any different.

Comment: @Barmar Ya it give kind a different result, but still looking only for one company.   If submit with out `[]` it looks for company1 if with out `[]` it looks for company2.  Do you think problem can be in my form?

Comment: The form should have inputs like `<input type="text" name="name[]">`

Comment: I don't see where in your PHP code you're accessing the form parameters.

Comment: @Barmar i updated my post

Comment: I still don't see where the PHP code is using the `company` parameters. But you need to change the HTML to `name="company[]"`

Comment: You need some kind of loop over the Laravel equivalent of `$_GET['company']`

Comment: Use `whereIn('company', [1, 2])`

Comment: @fubar Can you show an example? because i have not only one company, i will have many in future

Comment: @DmitryMalys - I've added an answer with a basic example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic example illustrating use of `whereIn`.

```
$companies = $request->company ?? [];
$products = Product::company($companies)->paginate(30);

class Product extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function company(Builder $query, ...$companies) 
    {
        return $query->whereIn('company', $companies);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Example using `whereIn` with OP's code.

```
class ProductFilters extends QueryFilter
{
    // ...

    public function make($maker)
    {
        return $this->builder->whereIn('company', (array) $maker);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: im sorry, im new around here and i dont know how to ask question. Thing is that i have other filters as well, like colors and etc

Comment: Sure, I was just trying to illustrate how `whereIn` works. It can easily be applied to your existing example, if that's indicative of your current setup. See my updated answer.